# SQL Create Table Integrity Constraints Order

Tags: sql

When using the 'CREATE TABLE' command in SQL, is there a specific order that the integrity constraints should be in? And by integrity constrains I mean 'NOT NULL', 'CHECK', 'UNIQUE' etc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter what order you put the constraints in. SQL is a declarative language so in general you'll have some leeway with the syntax..

**NOTE**

There is one caveat though. You haven't specified a RDBMS so I answered about SQL as an ANSI standard language. Certain implementations may impose some rules..

For instance, the following is valid in MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
  ColumnA INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ColumnB INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  ColumnC INT NOT NULL CHECK (ColumnC > 0) 
);
```

But the following will make MySQL unhappy, while the others will be fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
  ColumnA INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ColumnB INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  ColumnC INT CHECK (ColumnC > 0) NOT NULL   -- MySQL does not like this!!
);
```

Comment: Postgres is fine with all of them as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the quick reply and the note about the different RDBMSs!